# Last 24 hours of alerts (but date time is in Unix time - my script does convert to normal date time)

Tags: powershell

I am leveraging the Nutanix PowerShell API to get the last 24hrs of unresolved alerts and output it to an HTML report. The alerts created date time is in Unix time so I had to translate to normal date time format. Where I am stuck at is limiting the output to the last 24hours of alerts. Right now its showing all alerts from 8/31 to present day. I so far have the following:

```
$MyNTNXCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ntnxuserid, (Get-Content $NTNXCredPassPath | ConvertTo-SecureString )
$NTNXClusterList = import-csv -Path C:\path_to_list_of_clusters\ntnxclusters_list.csv

$NTNXAlertArray = @()
foreach($NTNXAlertCluster in $NTNXClusterList){

    $NTNXCluster = $NTNXAlertCluster.Name
    Connect-NutanixCluster -Server $NTNXCluster -UserName $MyNTNXCredential.UserName -Password $MyNTNXCredential.Password -AcceptInvalidSSLCerts -ForcedConnection

    $GetNTNXAlert = Get-NTNXAlert | where resolved -NE "True" | select alertTitle, message, severity, categories, impact, resolved, createdTimeStampInUsecs, lastOccurrenceTimeStampInUsecs
    foreach($alert in $GetNTNXAlert){ 
  
        $Days = 1     
        $NTNXAlertTitle = $alert.alertTitle
        $NTNXAlertMessage = $Alert.message
        $NTNXAlertSeverity = $Alert.severity
        $NTNXAlertCategories = $Alert.categories
        $NTNXAlertImpact = $Alert.impact
        $NTNXAlertResolved = $Alert.resolved
        $NTNXAlertCreated = $Alert.createdTimeStampInUsecs
        $NTNXLastOccurance= $Alert.lastOccurrenceTimeStampInUsecs

        $myTimeZone=[System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")
        $NTNXCreatedDateTime = (New-Object -Type DateTime -ArgumentList 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds([math]::Floor($NTNXAlertCreated/1000000))
        $NTNXLastOccuranceDateTime = (New-Object -Type DateTime -ArgumentList 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds([math]::Floor($NTNXLastOccurance/1000000))
        
        $NTNXAlertArray += [PSCUSTOMOBJECT]@{
            "Nutanix Cluster" = $NTNXCluster
            "Nutanix Alert Title" = $NTNXAlertTitle
            "Nutanix Alert Message" = $NTNXAlertMessage
            "Nutanix Alert Severity" = $NTNXAlertSeverity
            "Nutanix Alert Category" = $NTNXAlertCategories
            "Nutanix Alert Impact" = $NTNXAlertImpact
            "Nutanix Alert Resolved" = $NTNXAlertResolved
            "Nutanix Alert Created" = $NTNXCreatedDateTime
            "Nutanix Alert Last Occurred" = $NTNXLastOccuranceDateTime
        }
    }
}
$NTNXAlertHTML = $NTNXAlertArray | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>NTNX Alerts</h3>"
```

I have done some searching online but what is throwing me off is the unix time and then how to add the ability to filter only for events in the past 2hrs. Anyone have any ideas on how I can approach this. I may be looking at this in the wrong way. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? From data that you have now you want to get only those form past 24 hours, do I undestand you correctly?

Comment: well, I want to pull in the alerts for the past 24hours only. Right now it's pulling all alerts unresolved going back to 8/31. The $Alert.createdTimeStampInUsecs and $Alert.lastOccurrenceTimeStampInUsecs is in UnixTime which is why I added the $mytimezone and other declarations to convert it to normal readable time. So thats what is throwing me on where to add on the script to just give me that last 24hrs of alerts.

Comment: what version of powershell do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using neat `DateTime` objects, you can filter on them quite easily. For example, insert a filter in your last line:

```
$NTNXAlertHTML = $NTNXAlertArray | Where-Object {$_."Nutanix Alert Created" -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)} | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>NTNX Alerts</h3>"
```